# How to use InstaSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, instasharp

What authInfo ?I want run this code but I dont know find authInfo .
  var users = new InstaSharp.Endpoints.Users.Authenticated ( config, authInfo )

please if you have code Instasharp sdk in asp.net ,you share

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the binaries instead of GitHub code, there are some small differences: the `OAuth` class is called `InstaSharp.Auth`. 

For `authInfo`; You can create a new instance of `InstaSharp.AuthInfo` object with no parameters and set the access token to use it wherever you like:

```
 AuthInfo authInfo = new AuthInfo();
 authInfo.Access_Token = "the code you get after user authentication";
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Get latest version from [GitHub](https://github.com/InstaSharp/InstaSharp), then you can use following code:

```
    var config = new InstagramConfig(clientId, secret, "http://localhost");
    var oauth = new OAuth(config);
    var link = OAuth.AuthLink(config, scopes, OAuth.ResponseType.Code);
```

Redirect user to link or just open this link in browser and authorize your application. Then you will get response code. Copy and paste this code to RequestToken method

```
    var authInfo = await oauth.RequestToken("CODE_HERE");
    var tagsApi = new InstaSharp.Endpoints.Tags(config, authInfo);
    var tagInfo = tagsApi .Get("tagName");
```

Comment: very poor documentation for instasharp. Thumbs down.

Comment: What about the **code** ? User or the developer will copy that code?

Comment: Awful thumbs down too

Comment: What's a `scopes`?

Answer (score 1):

```
Install latest InstaSharp and just do this:

private InstagramConfig _config;
public async Task< ActionResult> somename(string code)
        {
            if (code != null)
            {
               _config = new InstagramConfig(["InstgramClientId"],
                                                 ["InstgramClientSecret"],
                                                ["InstgramRedirectUrl"]
                                                 );

                var instasharp = new InstaSharp.OAuth(_config);
                var authInfo = await instasharp.RequestToken(code);
                var user = new InstaSharp.Endpoints.Users(_config, authInfo);

                ViewBag.Username = user.OAuthResponse.User.Username;
                ViewBag.Token = authInfo.AccessToken;


                return View();
            }

            return View("name"); 
        }
```

Comment: welcome to SO and thank you for posting an answer. Please consider adding context to your code.